# Split data frame by same value/text and then merge vertically

Tags: r

I have data frame `df` as following:

```
 df$x1    df$x2     df$x3    df$x4     df$x5    df$x6          
 Acti     Acti     Arthrex  Arthrex    Aflac    Aflac     
  4         5        3         1        2         5
  1         3        5         2        1         4
```

I wish to split the data frame by text in first row and then merge vertically. My desired output would be like following:

```
 df$x1    df$x2           
 Acti     Acti         
  4         5     
  1         3     
 Arthrex  Arthrex
  3         1
  5         2
 Aflac    Aflac
  2         5
  1         4
```

Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a solution using dplyr (assuming your data is called df):

```
library(dplyr)

t(df) %>% # transpose the data so that the first row is now the first col
  as_data_frame() %>% # convert back to data.frame from matrix
  group_by(V1) %>% # group the data by the first column
  do(as_data_frame(t(.))) # transpose each group back to the correct orientation
```

`dplyr::do` lets you do arbitrary operations on each group then row binds the results back together into a data.frame.

Comment: your code is producing error. It producing `error: is.list(x) is not TRUE`.

Comment: I used `as.data.frame` instead of `as_data_frame` and it worked perfectly.